# QT4 and shell32.dll - use built-in windows icons

Tags: windows, qt, icons, qicon, shell32.dll

is there any possibility to do something like this in Linux (`QIcon::fromTheme("application-exit");`) in Windows too?

Is there any trick how to make app to have uniform look with actual system and theme? I also don't want to include my own icons, it is small application that will consist only from one executable file with a size of few kilobytes.

Comment: You could try [QStyle::standardIcon()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyle.html#standardIcon).

Comment: As far as I know the fromTheme() does only include freedesktop.org desktop environments and not windows ?